# How is the percentage of CPU usage calculated?

Tags: ubuntu, cpu

In my Ubuntu 12.04, with psensor, I saw a percentage number updated for cpu usage. I wonder how this percentage caculated? Specifically, what is the numerator and denominator in the ratio?

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The [processor usage percent](http://www.design-reuse.com/articles/8289/how-to-calculate-cpu-utilization.html) is calculated with "the amount of time that the processor is not on idle". I mean, this calc is made from a counter that register the usage of the "idle" running process. While another preocesses "rob" the processor power from the idle process, the idle processor consumer register is decreased by a factor; as the time line is fixed and constant, the (1-"%time in the idle taks") is the amount of processor load used for all processes running on a processor:

[image]

**Defining CPU utilization**

> For our purposes, I define CPU utilization, U, as the amount of time
>   not in the idle task, as shown in Equation 1.
>
> The idle task is the task with the absolute lowest priority in a
>   multitasking system. This task is also sometimes called the background
>   task or background loop, shown in Listing 1. This logic traditionally
>   has a while(1) type of loop. In other words, an infinite loop spins
>   the CPU waiting for an indication that critical work needs to be done.

*Listing 1: Simple example of a background loop*

```
int main( void )
{
   SetupInterrupts();
   InitializeModules();
   EnableInterrupts();

   while(1)      /* endless loop - spin in the background */
   {
      CheckCRC();
      MonitorStack();
      ... do other non-time critical logic here.
   }
}
```

> This depiction is actually an oversimplification, as some "real" work
>   is often done in the background task. However, the logic coded for
>   execution during the idle task must have no hard real-time
>   requirements because there's no guarantee when this logic will
>   complete. In fact, one technique you can use in an overloaded system
>   is to move some of the logic with less strict timing requirements out
>   of the hard real-time tasks and into the idle task.