# How do I see the CPU load of a server?

Tags: linux, cpu-usage

What is the command to see CPU load of a RedHat Linux server?

Answer (score 12):

### [`top`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Top_(Unix)) - The classic approach

[image]

### [`htop`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Htop) - The colorful approach

[image]

### [`mpstat`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mpstat) - The plain and simple

[image]

#### Notes

If you're wondering how to read the CPU load from the output of `top` or `mpstat`, please look at the **idle** values they print. The CPU load is the difference between 100% and the displayed value.

If you think that that's weird, please see our question: [How is the percentage of CPU usage calculated?](https://superuser.com/questions/432440/how-is-the-percentage-of-cpu-usage-calculated)

Comment: Thanks, but it gives cpu load per process. I want to see total CPU load, for example 85%

Comment: If you look at the top line in the first image (program top).  It has the line `load average`. The three values after that are the load average over time.

Comment: @alwbtc: They all give you that in various forms. If you look at the output of `mpstat` you see an `idle` value of `99.24`. This means I have a CPU load of `0.76%`. As @Hennes notes, there is also the [*load average*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Load_average) displayed, which is another *indicator* of CPU load. If you really only want a command that returns a single percent value, you'll probably want to post-process the output of `mpstat`.

Answer (score 4):

Personally I think looking at the **average** load of a period is best. Otherwise you might get quite different values depending on the timing. (e.g. enter a command and press [Enter] might yield a different result than if you pressed [Enter] a fraction of a second later.)

Some ways of checking the load average are:

1. `cat  /proc/loadavg`

   ```
   beetle:/proc>cat loadavg
   0.45 0.19 0.13 1/263 17588
   ```
2. `uptime` also shows the load.

   ```
   toad:/home/hennes>uptime
   4:03PM  up 155 days, 19:12, 38 users, load averages: 0.16, 0.17, 0.12
   ```
3. Via `top`. Look at he line `load averages:` in the upper right corner.
4. htop
5. mpstat
6. systat (e.g. systat -vmstat)

Most of these programs give you three numbers:

- The load average during the last minute.
- The load average during the last five minutes
- The load average during the last fifteen minutes.

If you have one core then a load of 1 more or less indicates that core is busy 100% of the time. This number can exceed 1 (or 100%). If that happens there is on average more then one process in the run queue.

If you have multiple CPU's then 100% (or 1.00) means that one average one core is busy all the time. E.g. with 4 core this could mean 1 core running flat out and 3 cores being idle. Or 4 cores running ¼ of the time.

Comment: Thanks, load average 0.45 means: 45% of CPU power is used?

Comment: 0.45 means that 45 of a single CPU core is used.  45% used, 55% idle. ---- If you have two core and get a load of 0.45 then 45% of a core is used and 155% is idle ; or both core are used 22.5% of the time and both core are idle 77.5% of the time.

Comment: just for sake of explicity: if i have a 24 cpu machine and `uptime` says `load average: 65.12, 64.98, 64.16` then this machine is heavily overloaded?

Comment: No. It might mean that.  But there are reasons why processses could be iin the run queue without actually using CPU time. (e.g. when waiting for an action).